# How to Change the BG of the Timeline

Tags: color, theme

I'm trying to change the color of the timeline BG in Blender to be more visible than the dark color it is now in the current theme I'm using. I can't find the setting to change it. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In User Preferences under *Themes > Dope Sheet > Theme Space > Window Background*:

[image: Here2]

[image: Here3]

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I change the color of it, but the timeline BG doesn't change at all. I'm using the latest Blender version.

Comment: Sorry, do it for "Dope Sheet" - I don't know where I got it in my head you were talking about the graph editor. I'll fix the screenshot.

Comment: That doesn't change the color of the Timeline BG in Blender either.

Comment: Strange... it does for me (see second image). I can't explain why it doesn't change on yours.

Comment: Welp, after trying a few more times, and restarting, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: However, when I switch to the Motion Tracking Tab, it goes back to dark grey. Not sure why that is.